# In Flex, for manually resizing datagrid, how can I keep the column widths reasonable?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Whenever you resize a datagrid by hand (not via code), the last column seems to retain most of the width. What's worse, whenever you extend it and shrink it to a large degree, the other columns can get smushed. Here's a perfect example:

[image: Datagrid Example]

The ideal solution would distribute width equally or in proportion to the length of the text. In addition, if would avoid covering text when it's not necessary. Now, setting the width to `0.5` in the example above does seem to alleviate the issue, but not prevent it entirely.

What I'd also like to know if there are any well polished, custom datagrids out there that solve this. From trying to find a solution, I suspect the only solutions available are more ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1):

I know two ways to avoid this problem.

1) Use `List` with special item renderer, which simulates columns (say `HBox` separated with rules), and header, which repeats the layout of item renderer. It's not very elegant solutions, but the resize is quite predictable. Also you can easily add sorting feature (by adding buttons to header), but I'm not sure if column resize is possible to implement here.

2) Use spark `s:DataGrid` from SDK 4.x. It hasn't got such resize problems AFAIK.